# Check if The system Date is correct in Vba

Tags: vba, date, authorization

Does anyone can help? How to check if a local system has a valid date setting using vba. To protect Code from being run after specified date.

The following code is not enough, it can be break by changing system date.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
If Date > DateSerial(2018, 5, 17) Then
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for any reply

Comment: Perhaps also have a very hidden sheet to store last save/open times and compare the current "Date" cannot be earlier than those? So eventually it will expire. And warn them that date tempering detected and will delete all the worksheet data? Alternatively, bring up IE, navigate to https://time.is/, or search "Date" in google. This method can be bypassed if disconnected from internet.

Answer (score 0):

A 2nd best solution to determine whether the system time has been tampered with may be to compare system date/time with the date/time of the most recent file in ...Appdata\Local\Temp. Disclaimer: there may be better sources for comparison, I do not know Windows that deep.